# Deserialize complex nested JSON with C#

Tags: c#, json

I want to read JSON that looks like this in C#. But I cant figure out how to pull out specific blocks from the JSON.

```
{
  "took": 32,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 3,
    "successful": 3,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 263,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": 29.078617,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "x",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "x",
        "_score": 29.078617,
        "_source": {
          "reference": "x",
          "locationList": [
            {
              "country": "x",
              "address": "x",
              "city": "x",
              "postalCode": "x",
              "latitude": "x",
              "county": "x",
              "municipal": "x",
              "longitude": "x"
            }
          ],
          "expires": "x",
          "businessName": "x",
          "employer": { "name": "x" },
          "source": "x",
          "published": "x",
          "title": "x",
          "uuid": "x",
          "properties": {
            "applicationdue": "x",
            "employer": "x"
          },
          "status": "ACTIVE"
        }
      },
      ....
```

- How do I parse the data from the **second** "hits"?

Haven't found any good reads on how to do it with multiple boxes within JSON, so hopefully someone with experience will know this one. Thanks.

Comment: One Option https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectToken.htm

Comment: The "second `hits`" (it's an array) is a property of the "first `hits`". That "first `hits`" is a property of your top level object. To deserialize this, build a set of classed that matches the structure of the JSON and deserialize everything into an instance of the top class

Comment: You could start from using proper words -- do you want to **parse** (i.e. you are writing a **parser**) or do you want to **deserialize** (i.e. you are using already existing library, like Newtonsoft).

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this

```
 var jsonResponse = JObject.Parse(yourJason);
 var jHits = (JArray)jsonResponse["hits"]["hits"]; //This way you'll get the second hits array.
```